# How can I get this api data in my snackbar? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

Here I need some help. I want to get the message response from api. How can I get it.

### Api Response :

```
   {
        "error": "validation_error",
        "message": {
            "phoneNumber": [
                "The phone number has already been taken."
            ],
            "password": [
                "The password and confirmed must match."
            ],
            "confirmed": [
                "The confirmed field is required."
            ]
        }
    }
```

I am trying to get with this function. I can only take the Error message with this

```
res.data['error']. I want to get data from api response "message" . How can I get this message List data.
```

---

```
if (res.data['error'] == 'validation_error') {
          Get.snackbar(
            'Validation error',
            res.data['error'],
            snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            colorText: Colors.red,
            // overlayBlur: 10,
          );
```

### This is the controller :

```
import 'package:Darucheeni/src/configs/appConfigs.dart';
import 'package:Darucheeni/src/pages/AuthPage/VerifyUserPage.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '../../pages/home/bottomAppBar.dart';

class LoginSignupControlleler extends GetxController {
  final dio = Dio();
  var isSignupPage = RxBool(true);
  //
  final fullNameReg = RxString('');
  final phoneNumberReg = RxString('');
  final passwordReg = RxString('');
  final confirmedReg = RxString('');
  //
  final phoneNumberLog = RxString('');
  final passwordLog = RxString('');
  final confirmedLog = RxString('');
  //
  userRegistration() async {
    try {
      final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final token = sharedPreferences.get('accessToken');
      final userName = sharedPreferences.get('userName');
      //
      final res = await dio.post(
        baseUrl + 'customer/register',
        data: {
          'fullName': fullNameReg.value,
          'phoneNumber': phoneNumberReg.value,
          'password': passwordReg.value,
          'confirmed': confirmedReg.value,
        },
      );

      print('<------------------------------');
      print(res.statusCode);
      print(res.headers);
      // print(res.body);
      // print(res.unauthorized);
      print(res.realUri);
      print(res.statusMessage);
      print(res.data);
      print(res.realUri);
      print(res.requestOptions);
      print('------------------------------>');

      if (res.data['status'] == 'success') {
        if (res.data['error'] == 'validation_error') {
          Get.snackbar(
            'Validation error',
            res.data['error'],
            snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            colorText: Colors.red,
            // overlayBlur: 10,
          );
        } else {
          Get.snackbar(
              'User Registration Successfull', 'Please Verify your account.');
          sharedPreferences.setString(
            'userName',
            fullNameReg.value,
          );
          print(userName);
          print(res.data);

          await Get.offAll(VerifyUserPage());
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  userLogin() async {
    try {
      final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      // final token = sharedPreferences.get('accessToken');
      //
      final res = await dio.post(
        baseUrl + 'customer/login',
        data: {
          'phoneNumber': phoneNumberLog.value,
          'password': passwordLog.value,
          'confirmed': confirmedLog.value,
        },
      );

      print('<------------------------------');
      print(res.statusCode);
      print(res.headers);
      // print(res.body);
      // print(res.unauthorized);
      print(res.realUri);
      print(res.statusMessage);
      print(res.data['token']);
      print(res.realUri);
      print(res.requestOptions);
      print('------------------------------>');

      if (res.data['status'] == 'success') {
        {
          Get.snackbar('Success', 'User Login Successfull');
          print(res.data['token']);
          sharedPreferences.setString(
            'accessToken',
            res.data['token'],
          );

          await Get.offAll(CustomBottomAppBar());
          print('$confirmedLog , $passwordLog , $phoneNumberLog');
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
// if (res.data['error'] == 'validation_error') {
//           Get.snackbar(
//             'Validation error',
//             res.data['error'],
//             snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
//             backgroundColor: Colors.white,
//             colorText: Colors.red,
//             // overlayBlur: 10,
//           );
//         }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote below, you can access the data you want.

```dart
final messageData = res['message'];
final phoneMessage = messageData['phoneNumber'][0]
final passwordMessage = messageData['password'][0]
final confirmedMessage = messageData['confirmed'][0]
```